# how only add record in join table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I have model `Program`, `Courses` and `Student`. There is many_to_many relationship between `program course` and `student course`...

So first i add `program's courses` then i show `program courses` to student so that he can take courses but problem is that whenever i create student courses it adds course in course table too i just want to add `course_id` and `student_id` in join table and don't want to add course in course table because courses are already there..

my course controller

```
def create
  @program = Program.find(params[:program_id]) if params[:program_id]
  @course = @program.courses.create(program_course_params) if @program
  @student = Student.find(params[:student_id]) if params[:student_id]
  if params[:student_id]
    params[:student].each do |cid|
      @course = @student.courses.create(name:cid) if @student
    end
  end
end
```

Form

```
 <table>
    <% @student.program.courses.each do |c| %>
    <tr><td><%=c.name %><td> 
    <td><%= check_box_tag "student[]",c.name,:name %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    <tr>
   </table>

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students
    has_and_belongs_to_many  :programs

end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
    has_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :courses

    belongs_to :program
end
```

Comment: what does params[:student] contain exactly ?

Comment: Kindly post all your models code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
def create
  @program = Program.find(params[:program_id]) if params[:program_id]
  @course = @program.courses.create(program_course_params) if @program
  @student = Student.find(params[:student_id]) if params[:student_id]
  if params[:student_id]
    params[:student].each do |cid|
      course_to_add = Course.find_by_id(cid)
      @course = @student.courses << course_to_add unless course_to_add.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Still very inefficient

Comment: though querying for the course is inefficient, what would be a quicker way to safely make sure you aren't creating join_objects for courses that don't exist if the form got bad input?

Answer (score 2):

this line is telling rails to create an entirely new course, and associate that course to the student

```
@course = @student.courses.create(name:cid) if @student
```

i believe you mean to shovel the course onto the students array of courses like this:

```
@student.courses << course
```

or maybe, since it appears your students_courses table also includes a name attribute rather than simply having id's of the joined objects, you may need to do this

```
StudentsCourse.create( student: @student, course: @course, name: cid)
```

there may be some errors in the above code, but without seeing more of your source code it is hard to tell from the way the question is presented whether i have the name of the join table correct. this will also require a model for the join table, if you don't already have that.

Comment: This is a LOT closer to an answer but you don't have a join model since it's `HABTM`

Comment: not necessarily. a HABTM works without a model for the join table, but still works fine if there is a model.

Comment: How do you know? HABTM tables have no primary key, which I presumed to be required for Rails models?

Comment: i've done it before and just went back to test that it's functioning the way i thought it was in an app i've been working on. ohhh. i should've also pointed out that you not only need the model but a migration too. but you can have those and then still use a HABTM rather than has_many through:

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is highly inefficient, you'll be better using the [`collection_singular_ids`](https://ernie.io/2010/10/02/the-underused-collection_singular_ids-method/) method if you want to just populate the join:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :programs do
  resources :students do
    match :courses, via: [:get, :put] #-> url.com/programs/:program_id/students/:student_id/courses
  end

#app/controllers/students_controller.rb
class StudentsController < ApplicationController 
   def courses
     @program = Program.find params[:program_id]
     @student = Student.find params[:student_id]
     @courses = Course.all
     @student.update course_id_params if request.put?
   end

   private

   def course_id_params
     params.require(:student).permit(course_ids: [])
   end
end

#app/views/students/courses.html.erb
<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_check_boxes :course_ids, @courses, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: won't this overwrite the course_ids on the student every time? that's fine if it's the intended use, but i was under the impression that old courses should remain, and new ones get added.

Comment: Yep but since it's check boxes, each time you load the `courses` action, any existing `@student.courses` will be checked. Overwriting the entire join array then becomes a case of setting the courses you want

Comment: good point, you're clearly paying better attention than i am.